# Which mask is Wade/Deadpool wearing in this scene?

Tags: reference, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

At the end of the movie, when Wade is showing his new face to Vanessa, Deadpool is wearing a second mask:

[image]

Who is this supposed to be?

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain?

Comment: This is a reasonable question - the scene goes by quite quickly; I've had to explain it to friends.

Comment: “There is no way you don’t know Hugh Jackman” Could be the reason of the down vote.

Comment: @majidarif I suppose that could be why someone downvoted. But I honestly wasn't really sure who it was either. It's hard to make out the features on the mask. Especially with all the wrinkles (on the mask, not Hugh Jackman).

Comment: In the movie itself, I found recognition of Hugh Jackman easy.   The picture above isn't as recognizable to me.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Its Hugh Jackman, the actor who plays Wolverine in the "mainstream" x-men movie series.

Its one of many fourth-wall-breaking Hugh Jackman / Wolverine jokes in the movie.

Comment: in addition to that, during the intro, you see a magazine cover with Ryan Reynolds as the "sexiest man of the year" (I don't know which year), he chose Hugh Jackman because of the latter also being voted "sexiest man of the year" beforehand

Comment: There are more references in Deadpool 2 too.

Comment: Deadpool has always been making fun of Wolverine on account of them both having regeneration/healing factor - /s I mean they're basically the same person! /s

Comment: I think it more accurate to say that Deadpool is completely obsessed with Wolverine (in both a love and a hate way). And Spiderman, but that's a different topic completely.

Comment: *Is* it Hugh Jackman (and thus a fourth wall break)? Or is isn’t it rather Wolverine (and thus more logical, given his Wolverine obsession, and entirely in Universe)? It vaguely looks as if Wolverine’s signature sideburns might be missing in the picture but I can’t see it clearly.

Comment: I'd say they have a relationship due to the XMen Origins: Wolverine movie.  Reynolds played Dead Pool (Wade Wilson) in that movie, too, but ultimately wasn't happy with how the character was portrayed.  Hence, one of the final scenes in Dead Pool 2 that I don't want to spoil for others.  But there were a lot of tie-ins for both Dead Pool movies that relate back to that XMen movie.

Comment: @KonradRudolph .. I think its Jackman and not Wolverine - due to the hair being less "full" than Wolverine's and the beard is evenly short whereas Wolverine often has it fuller at the sides trims it very short on the chin and moustache.  I believe its taken from this magazine cover ... https://goo.gl/images/eUdAFi

Comment: @KonradRudolph When hearing Xavier's name he asks if it's Stewart or McAvoy. Using an actor (or their name) is not unheard of in Deadpool.